# Why does react reconciliation preserve the constant sibilings when order is changed

Tags: reactjs, browser, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I'm checking [react reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). It says that when traversing the children, React will iterate over both lists of children at the same time and generate a mutation whenever there’s a difference.

I made a simple example:

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {

    state = {
        first: true
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        this.setState({
            first: !this.state.first
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='top'>
                {this.state.first ? <span>xyz</span> : undefined}
                <div>abc</div>
                <div>efg</div>
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>click me</button>
            </div>)
    }
}
```

On click, the first child (span element) will get in and out of the list of children. From React's point of view, iterating one by one, it should look like all elements have changed. Therefore React should re-render the DOM for all of these 4 children (including button).

But checking the DOM inspector in Firefox and Chrome I see highlight only on the *span* element, not on all four, meaning the DOM is preserved for the three unchanged elements. Why?

[image: highlight is not seen on this picture but the span element gets highlighted]
(highlight is not seen on this picture but the span element gets highlighted on button click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in my example is that the first child (the `span`) is never really removed from the children array but only toggles between `span` and undefined. So there are always 4 children and the reorder (index shifting) never happens.

That's why react knows to match the elements and update only span `DOM` element and leave the other 3 as they are.

Answer (score 0):

React compares element attributes in this case. From the React docs:

> ## DOM Elements Of The Same Type
>
> When comparing two React DOM elements of
> the same type, React looks at the attributes of both, keeps the same
> underlying DOM node, and only updates the changed attributes. For
> example:

This is also the reason why you need to supply a key when you create a list of elements dynamically. If that key is not supplied and the list changes because of prop or state changes, all list items need to be removed and appended.

You may want to read the following article, where this phenomenon is explained more thoroughly. https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

**From the article:**

> Let me explain, a key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM
> elements. What happens if you push an item to the list or remove
> something in the middle? If the key is same as before React assumes
> that the DOM element represents the same component as before. But that
> is no longer true.

Comment: But the point I'm making is that react compares children of  "outer" div one by one, in order. Therefore after button click it will see that they differ either in type (div->span) or in attributes (key and content) as they have been reordered. So react has to modify all 4 elements not just the one added. But as I see in dev tools inspector only one is modified. Which of this sentences is wrong according to your answer?

Comment: _So react has to modify all 4 elements not just the one added._ This is not true. React does not depend on the order of elements in the virtual DOM in its reconciliation process. When the first element is conditionally removed, it does not affect its siblings.

Comment: I think this section https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children says just that, that react has to mutate every children?